# BroadcastReceiver отображение оповещения в виде полноэкранного Activity или аналога входящему звонку в Viber,Skype,Telegram и другим месенджерам

Tags: java, android

Я создал
public class IncomingSms extends BroadcastReceiver
прописал в manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />
```

и когда это приложение было актуально , в версии андроид 4.х , я просто вызывал context.starActivity(intent);
и всё прекрасно работало, но прошло много времени и Google решила испортить разработчикам жизнь, и теперь это не работает в Android 10+
Я также пробовал через

```
windowManager = (WindowManager) context.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
    LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

WindowManager.LayoutParams params;
int LAYOUT_FLAG;
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
    LAYOUT_FLAG = WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_APPLICATION_OVERLAY;
} else {
    LAYOUT_FLAG = WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_PHONE;
}

params = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
        LAYOUT_FLAG,
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCHABLE | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_IN_SCREEN | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE,
        PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);
windowManager.addView(windowLayout, params);
```

на что получаю E/SmsReceiver: Exception smsReceiverandroid.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window android.view.ViewRootImpl$W@726aafb -- permission denied for window type 2038

я Пробовал создать как было описано в документации Notification
с добавлением к нему setFullScreenIntent

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
    CharSequence name = channel_name;
    String description = channel_description;
    int importance = NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH;
    NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel(SMS_MSG, name, importance);
    channel.setDescription(description);
    // Register the channel with the system; you can't change the importance
    // or other notification behaviors after this
    NotificationManager notificationManager = context.getSystemService(NotificationManager.class);
    notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel);
}
Intent fullScreenIntent = new Intent(context, AlertActivity.class);
fullScreenIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
fullScreenIntent.setFlags(FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
fullScreenIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
fullScreenIntent.putExtra(ID_BOILER, boilers.get(b).get_id());
fullScreenIntent.putExtra(SMS_MSG, message);

PendingIntent fullScreenPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0,
        fullScreenIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder =
    new NotificationCompat.Builder(context, SMS_MSG)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.alarme)
            .setContentTitle("Incoming call")
            .setContentText("(919) 555-1234")
            .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_HIGH)
            .setCategory(NotificationCompat.CATEGORY_CALL)
            .setFullScreenIntent(fullScreenPendingIntent, true);

Notification incomingCallNotification = notificationBuilder.build();

NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
// notificationId is a unique int for each notification that you must define
notificationManager.notify(1010, incomingCallNotification);
```

и да оповещение создаётся, при нажатии на него открывает полноэкранная Activity с нужным мне функционалом, но это нас абсолютно не устраивает.
Основная логика приложения завязана на обработке SMS с определенных номеров и формирования чёткого ГРОМКОГО оповещения о них в виде орущего на всю комнату телефона. В идеале это мгновенно открытая активность с громким оповещением о случившейся аварии.
Любые пермишены допустимы , т.к. его не требуется публиковать в Google Play, хотя если кто то предложит вариант который работает учитывая все текущие ограничия Google , это будет идеально.
Меня вполне устроить реализация оповещения по манере звонка Viber, Skype, или аналогичных месенджеров, когда оповещение сопровождается постоянным звуком и отображается либо с верху экрана как постоянно вибрирующий индикатор с кнопками, или выскакивает что в идеале на полный экран как звонилка.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В моём вопросе отражён и ответ, как это ни странно, просто по странному стечению обстоятельств я столкнулся с багом в системе.
Я перепробовал много способов и одним из вариантов запустить старое поведение это добавить в манифест

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW" />
```

и вы настройках приложения появляется пункт "Поверх других приложений" или "Всегда сверху" его ручками пользователя требуется установить в true , и тогда начинает работать старое поведение context.startActivity

Второй и более правильный вариант это использовать Notification, а именно setFullScreenIntent. Его поведение сводится к тому что полноэкранная Activity открывается только в том случае если ваш телефон находится в заблокированном состоянии, если же он разблокирован и вы им пользуетесь то появляется оповещение нажав на которое открывается полноэкранная активность. Я столкнулся с багом, если вы хотя-бы раз добавил в ваш манифест файл выше указанный permission, то Notification будут корректно отображаться у вас в шторке но не будет выскакивать в верху экрана и в заблокированном состоянии также перестанет автоматически открываться Activity. Я очень долго бился над этой проблемой и случайно наткнулся на это странное поведение, помогает удаление приложения и установка нового, уже без этого permission.